# Get results only with max change?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to return only results that have the highest percentage of change. Table looks like

```
item      price1    price2
a         1         2
b         3         5
c         2         3
```

I would only want it to return a, like this:

```
item      price1    price2   percent_change
a         1         2        200%
```

I tried this

```
   select item, price1, price2, max(a.mPrice) as my_output from (select item, 
  ((price2-price1)/price1) * 100 as mPrice from table) a
```

but it says the indetifier is invalid (assuming that's `a.mPrice`). I've tried using `having` to only check for the max, but that didn't work, it still return all the results.

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious but I can't think of what it is. I'm guessing that using max(a.mPrice) wouldn't actually get the max like I need, but I'm not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
select item, price1, price2, ((price2 - price1)/price1) * 100 as my_output from table
group by item, price1, price2
having ((price2 - price1)/price1) * 100 = (select( max(((price2 - price1)/price2) * 100)) from table)
```

It's messy, but does what I need it to.

Comment: You can simplify it by using my_output as variable in having clause so you don't have to calculate that multiple times.

Also, check my answer for even simpler solution.

Comment: Tried doing that, but can't use it since it's an alias. Unless you mean declaring it beforehand, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Your table `a` does not have anything but `item` and `mPrice` so fetching `price1` and `price2` in outer query does not work.

But you can do it even without such subquery

```
SELECT item, price1, price2, ((price2-price1)/price1)*100 as growth
FROM products
ORDER BY growth DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

First, choose all three attributes and calculate growth, then order by growth descending and only take the top value.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16b7c/7

Comment: That works, so long as their is only one number with the max. I should've included that in my data, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Simple query if you want only max percentage

```
SELECT item, price1, price2, MAX(((price2-price1)/price1) * 100) percent_change FROM items
```

Comment: I figured that would work at first, but that returns all of the items. I figured it out, though.